# Strip HTML from web page on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, nsstring

This is my code:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.engadget.com"];
NSString *webPage=[[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

In the webPage string I got an html page of the link. In that string there is lot of tags and text. I want  to take only body of the text without any tags.

I want to display that text into my UITextView. How can I do that?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Remove HTML Tags From an NSString on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer and is exactly what you are looking for:

Write the following script in the webView delegate method. (`UIWebviewdidfinishLoading`)

```
NSString *myText = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.textContent"];
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I tried, [this](http://rudis.net/content/2009/01/21/flatten-html-content-ie-strip-tags-cocoaobjective-c) did the job best. Even though the NSSCanner is not the smaerter solution for this, if the html/xml is well formed you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Better Solution:

```
- (NSString *)flattenHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        // find start of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ; 

        // find end of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        // replace the found tag with a space
        //(you can filter multi-spaces out later if you wish)
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:
                           [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text]
                     withString:@" "];

    } // while //

    return html;

}
```

Reference: http://rudis.net/content/2009/01/21/flatten-html-content-ie-strip-tags-cocoaobjective-c

Comment: This would appear to be a direct copy and paste from this blog post: http://rudis.net/content/2009/01/21/flatten-html-content-ie-strip-tags-cocoaobjective-c

You should provide attribution when copying someone else's code.

Comment: my bad. I was in train when I wrote it.