# Remove part of an NSString

Tags: ios4, nsstring, substring, explode

I have an NSString as follows:

```
<img alt="996453912" src="http://d2gg0uigdtw9zz.cloudfront.net/large/996453912.jpg" /><a href="http://www.dealcatcher.com/shop4tech-coupons">Shop4Tech Coupons</a>
```

I only need the first part (before the `<a href` part), and I cannot figure out how to remove the second part.

I have tried a ton, but it has not worked.

Comment: Which methods have you tried?

Comment: I have tried Componentsseperatedby and have looked for others, but cannot find others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use something like:

```
NSRange rangeOfSubstring = [string rangeOfString:@"<a href"];

if(rangeOfSubstring.location == NSNotFound)
{
     // error condition — the text '<a href' wasn't in 'string'
}

// return only that portion of 'string' up to where '<a href' was found
return [string substringToIndex:rangeOfSubstring.location];
```

So the two relevant methods are [substringToIndex:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringToIndex:) and [rangeOfString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:).

Answer (score 3):

There is a section in the NSString Class reference about [Finding Characters and Substrings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) which lists some helpful methods.

And in the String Programming Guide There is a section on [Searching, Comparing and Sorting Strings.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/SearchingStrings.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000149-CJBBGBAI)

I'm not being shirty in pointing out these links. You've said that you've couldn't find methods so here are a couple of references to help you know where to look. Learning how to read the documentation is part of learning how to use the Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch Frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something similar to this modified version of what was posted as an answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4886998/283412. This will take your HTML string and strip out the formatting. Just modify the while part to remove the regex of what you want to strip:

```
-(void)myMethod
{
   NSString* htmlStr = @"<some>html</string>";
   NSString* strWithoutFormatting = [self stringByStrippingHTML:htmlStr];
}

-(NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString*)str
{
  NSRange r;
  while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
  {
     str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  }
  return str;
}
```