# Remove http:// from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsstring

How do I remove certain text from a `NSString` such as "http://"? It needs to be exactly in that order. Thanks for your help!

Here is the code I am using, however the http:// is not removed. Instead it appears http://http://www.example.com. What should I do? Thanks!

```
NSString *urlAddress = addressBar.text;
[urlAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", addressBar.text];
NSLog(@"The user requested this host name: %@", urlAddress);
```

Comment: You are again adding the same string. There is no need of 3rd line if you want to remove http://

Comment: If the user does not enter http://, then the UIWebView will work. However, if the user does enter http://, then the UIWebView will not work. By removing any http:// there is and then reinserting it once, I am guaranteed that the NSString will look like this: http:// www.google.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove part of an NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423248/remove-part-of-an-nsstring)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Like this?

```
NSString* stringWithoutHttp = [someString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
```

(if you want to remove text at the beginning only, do what jtbandes says - the code above will replace occurrences in the middle of the string as well)

Comment: @Jack Humphries - Krishnabhadra is right, you don't assign the changed value of urlAddress when you do stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution which takes care of http & https:

```
    NSString *shortenedURL = url.absoluteURL;

    if ([shortenedURL hasPrefix:@"https://"]) shortenedURL = [shortenedURL substringFromIndex:8];
    if ([shortenedURL hasPrefix:@"http://"]) shortenedURL = [shortenedURL substringFromIndex:7];
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *newString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://"
                                                          withString:@""
                                                             options:NSAnchoredSearch // beginning of string
                                                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [myString length])]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is :

```
NSString *str = @"http//abc.com";  
NSArray *arr = [str componentSeparatedByString:@"//"];  
NSString *str1 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];       //   http  
NSString *str2 = [arr objectAtIndex:1];       //   abc.com
```

Answer (score 3):

if http:// is at the start of the string you can use

```
 NSString *newString  = [yourOriginalString subStringFromIndex:7];
```

or else as SVD suggested

**EDIT: AFter seeing question EDIT**

change this line

```
[urlAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
```

to

```
urlAddress  = [urlAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the thread is still active and showed up in my search to remove the prefix from a URL (not NSString)... there is a one-liner if you are starting with a URL:

```swift
String(url.absoluteString.dropFirst((url.scheme?.count ?? -3) + 3))
```

Comment: hmmmmm, smart 

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option;

```
NSMutableString *copiedUrl = [[urlAddress mutablecopy] autorelease];
[copiedUrl deleteCharactersInRange: [copiedUrl rangeOfString:@"http://"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you wish to trim both sides and also write less code:

```
NSString *webAddress = @"http://www.google.co.nz";

// add prefixes you'd like to filter out here
NSArray *prefixes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"https:", @"http:", @"//", @"/", nil];

for (NSString *prefix in prefixes)
    if([webAddress hasPrefix:prefix]) webAddress = [webAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:prefix withString:@"" options:NSAnchoredSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [webAddress length])];

// add suffixes you'd like to filter out here
NSArray *suffixes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"/", nil];

for (NSString *suffix in suffixes)
    if([webAddress hasSuffix:suffix]) webAddress = [webAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:suffix withString:@"" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [webAddress length])];
```

This code will remove specified prefixes from the front and suffixes from the back (like a trailing slash). Simply add more substrings to the prefix/suffix array to filter for more.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

For replacing all occurrences:

```
let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "http://", with: "")
```

For replacing occurrences at the start of the string:

```
let newString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "http://", with: "", options: .anchored)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using swift and have arrived here.

```
extension String {

   func withoutHttpPrefix() -> String {
       var idx: String.Index?;
       if self.hasPrefix("http://www.") {
          idx = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 11)
       } else if hasPrefix("https://www.") {
           idx = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 12)
       } else if self.hasPrefix("http://") {
          idx = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
       } else if hasPrefix("https://") {
           idx = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: 8)
       }

       if idx != nil {
           return String(self[idx!...])
       }
       return self
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OR

```
+(NSString*)removeOpeningTag:(NSString*)inString tag:(NSString*)inTag {
    if ([inString length] == 0 || [inTag length] == 0) return inString;
    if ([inString length] < [inTag length]) {return inString;}
    NSRange tagRange= [inString rangeOfString:inTag];   
    if (tagRange.location == NSNotFound || tagRange.location != 0) return inString; 
    return [inString substringFromIndex:tagRange.length]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString* newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys bit late but I come with a generic way
Let's say:

```
NSString *host = @"ssh://www.somewhere.com";
NSString *scheme = [[[NSURL URLWithString:host] scheme] stringByAppendingString:@"://"]; 
// This extract ssh and add :// so we get @"ssh://" note that this code handle any scheme http, https, ssh, ftp ....
NSString *stripHost = [host stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:scheme withString:@""]; 
// Result : stripHost = @"www.somewhere.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more general way:

```
- (NSString*)removeURLSchemeFromStringURL:(NSString*)stringUrl {
    NSParameterAssert(stringUrl);
    static NSString* schemeDevider = @"://";

    NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:stringUrl];
    [scanner scanUpToString:schemeDevider intoString:nil];

    if (scanner.scanLocation <= stringUrl.length - schemeDevider.length) {
        NSInteger beginLocation = scanner.scanLocation + schemeDevider.length;
        stringUrl = [stringUrl substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(beginLocation, stringUrl.length - beginLocation)];
    }

    return stringUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will remove any scheme including http, https, etc.

```
NSRange dividerRange = [str rangeOfString:@"://"];
NSString *newString = [str substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange(dividerRange)];
```