# How do I strip HTML tags from my feed before displaying them in table cells?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, feed

I am reading a feed which gives the data with some html tags like

```
<p> this is a test string </p>.
```

I need to display this in UITableViewCell. The problem I have is , the html tags also gets displayed. How can I just show the text without html tag .??

Any help is greatly appreciated …!!!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the string through some stripping code before adding it to your tableview.

```
NSString *str = @"<p> this is a test string </p>";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<p>" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</p>" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<h1>" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</h1>" withString:@""];
//etc....

//new string equals @"this is a test string"
```

Comment: What if you have any css styles like: <p class="first">...</p> ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can search & replace those tags, or put the string you get from the server into UIWebView. It should present the html as it is.