# Parse NSString from right hand side?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

```
>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2009&nbsp;RX7)</font></td>
>monospace" size="-1">214869&nbsp;(2007&nbsp;PAZ)</font></td>
>monospace" size="-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;4155&nbsp;Accord</font></td>
```

I wonder if someone could offer me a little help, I have a list of NSString items (See Above) that I want to parse some data from. My problem is that there are no tags that I can use within the strings nor do the items I want have fixed positions. The data I want to extract is:

```
2009 RX7
2007 PAZ
4155 Accord
```

My thinking is that its going to be easier to parse from the right hand end, remove the `</font></td>` and then use ";" to separate the data items:

```
(2009&nbsp RX7)
(2007&nbsp PAZ)
4155&nbsp Accord
```

which can them be cleaned up to match the example given. Any pointers on doing this or working through from the right would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `Regular expressions` should do the trick. You might want to dive into them...

Comment: Is it always the last thing before `</font>`?

Comment: Your input resembles HTML, maybe you will find something useful in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone) and the following answers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes, the line always ends </font></td> and the bit I need it everything upto the second semi-colon (working from the right).

Comment: @basvk I will do just that, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think you are better off with a regex.  So my solution would be:

Regex of: `([0-9]+)[^;]+;([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

Which for all the example text provides 3 matches.  ie for:

```
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2009&nbsp;RX7)</font></td>
```

0: `2009&nbsp;RX7)<`

1: `2009`

2: `RX7`

I haven't coded this up, but did test the Regex at [www.regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com/)

Regex's are implemented via [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and are available in iOS 4.0 and later.

**Edit**

Given that this appears to be a web scraping application, you never know when those pesky HTML code monkeys will change their output and break your carefully crafted matching methodology.  As such I would change my regex to:

```
([0-9]+)([^;]+;)+([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

Which adds an extra group, but allows for any number of `&nbsp;` elements between the number and the string.

Comment: Thanks you Peter, thats a great help, is there any chance you can break down what the bits of the exp do. I have not used regular expressions before and want to learn them now, a simple this bit does this would greatly help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
NSString *str = @">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2009&nbsp;RX7)</font></td>";
NSRange fontRange = [str rangeOfString:@"</Font>" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange lastSemi = [str rangeOfString:@";" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, fontRange.location-1)];
NSRange priorSemi = [str rangeOfString:@";" options:NSBackwardsSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, lastSemi.location-1)];
NSString *yourString = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(priorSemi.location+1, fontRange.location-1)];
```

The key element here is the `NSBackwardsSearch` search option.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
NSString *s = @">monospace\" size=\"-1\">&nbsp;&nbsp;4155&nbsp;Accord</font></td>";
NSArray *strArray = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
// you're interested in last two objects
NSArray *tmp = [strArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(strArray.count - 2, 2)];
```

In tmp you'll have something like:

```
"4155&nbsp",
"Accord</font></td>"
```

strip unneeded chars and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex;
NSTextCheckingResult *match;

NSString *pattern = @"([0-9]+)&nbsp;([A-Za-z0-9]+)[)]?</font></td>";
NSString *string = @">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(2009&nbsp;RX7)</font></td>";

regex = [NSRegularExpression
         regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
         error:nil];


match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSLog(@"'%@'", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]]);
NSLog(@"'%@'", [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]]);
```

NSLog output:

'2009'
'RX7'