# How to remove html tags from a parsed text on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, parsing, tags

I am parsing a text and store it in a NSString variable. However when I try to display the NSString on screen I can see, within the text,  the html tags like: `<br>`. How can I remove this tags from my text and replace them with a space or something?

Comment: You can use a regex to match all tags, and remove them? If you consider anything between two angle brackets a tag, it's easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"This is<br>a string";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@""];
```

Comment: Perfect that was exactly what i was looking for! I want to remove the </br> too so is there a way i can remove them both with one line of code or must i copy this line once more to remove the </br> tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
    NSRange myRange;
    NSString *myString = [[self copy] autorelease];
    while ((myRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"<br>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    myString = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:myRange withString:@""];
    return myString; 
}
```