# iOS NSMutableString Remove <br> tags

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, nsxmlparser, nsmutablestring

I have an iPhone app and this is how i am parsing titles in an RSS feed using NSXMLParser:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        [self setTitle:currentString];
}
```

This works perfectly fine. Now i am dealing with another feed that contains titles with 
 tags in it and i want to remove them. I have seen different questions on StackOverflow like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879608/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-a-parsed-text-on-ios) that gives the code to replace the 
 tags with empty string. This is how i modified my code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    currentString = [[currentString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>" withString:@""] mutableCopy];
    [self setTitle:currentString];
}
```

But this doesn't work and shows the same text in the output without removing 
 tags. Can anyone point out what i am doing wrong and how can i correct it?

Comment: What is the currentString here? You are initializing a string here and then you replace <br> in it.

Comment: @Suresh currentString is a NSMutableString

Comment: @AJ112 We guessed that. It couldn't be anything else after you assign a pointer to `NSMutableString` to it. I think Suresh was asking for some context, such as: 1. is it an instance variable or what? 2. What is it used for (or what is it supposed to do)? 3. what do you expect the output to be, what's the (erroneous) output and 4. how does that relate to this variable?

Comment: @H2CO3 In my .h file, i am using declaring it as NSMutableString *currentString; and then in .m file i am using the currentString to alloc and initialise in every if statement in didStartElement to retrieve different tags in the rss feed. Right now its returning the same output without removing the <br> tags that i want to remove

Comment: @Suresh check my reply to H2CO3 above

Comment: @AJ112 Did you consider using `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString` instead of reallocating and reinitializing and copying the string each time?

Comment: @H2CO3 i didn't get what you just said. I think thats what i am doing, taking the currentString using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOFString withString

Comment: @AJ112 `replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:` is not the same as `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOFString:withString:`... Read the documentation of `NSMutableString`.

Comment: You should put more of your code because with your example you are just replacing <br> in an empty string... Just after initialization the string is empty, it won't have anything to replace

Comment: @slecorne actually its returning the output but without removing the br tags so that means its not empty

Comment: add `NSLog(@"%@", currentString)` just after the replace, it should be empty according to me. You are surely setting it with another value somewhere else

Comment: @H2CO3 tried replaceOccurrencesOfString withString using this quesion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647292/nsmutablestring-stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstring-warning and it didn't work. According to this question stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString should also work if i use mutableCopy which i am already using. So both doesn't work

Comment: @slecorne if i use NSLog it gives empty string but in the simulator and device its returning the title. As you said i am setting it somewhere else, In my UITableViewController i am setting it as follow with item being instance of this class    cell.titleLabel.text = [item title];

Comment: So move your code to replace the <br> juste before setting title of the cell. And you can remove all the useless `[[NSMutableString alloc] init];` in your parser

Comment: @slecorne i have moved the code exactly before setting the cell and it worked just fine all thanks to you. Kindly write it as an answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try one of these functions, that might be helpful to you

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Remove HTML Tags
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString
{
    NSMutableString *outString = [[[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:inputString] autorelease];

    if ([inputString length] > 0)
    {
        NSRange r;

        while ((r = [outString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [outString deleteCharactersInRange:r];
        }
    }

    return outString;
}

- (NSString *)stripTags:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL;
    NSString *tempText = nil;

    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tempText];

        if (tempText != nil)
            [html appendString:tempText];

        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];

        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];

        tempText = nil;
    }

    return html;
}
```

Comment: yes i have tried such method but they are not any different from the stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString that i am using. Whether i use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString or i use the methods you described, i get the same output