# removal of HTML tags which is coming in xml webservice

Tags: objective-c, xml

I have problem in this & tag in given xml webservice,

```
     <description>I am trying to find in a timely manner: 1) 2 ea. fast unload solenoid 
    valves/Coils 2) 2 ea. Load Solenoid Valves &amp; Coils 3) 2 ea. Unload Normal
     Solenoid Valves/Coils for the following: Model # SSCA075AN Serial #0277468</description>
```

After parse above xml  with nsxmlparser i am getting it  like given below:

```
      I am trying to find in a timely manner: 1) 2 ea. fast unload solenoid valves/Coils   2) 2 ea. Load Solenoid Valves 
      &
      amp; Coils 3) 2 ea. Unload Normal Solenoid Valves/Coils for the following: Model # SSCA075AN Serial # 0277468
```

I have to show it in combined string.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The result looks okay.

Comment: I have to show  like this :                                         I am trying to find in a timely manner: 1) 2 ea. fast unload solenoid valves/Coils   2) 2 ea. Load Solenoid Valves & Coils 3) 2 ea. Unload Normal Solenoid Valves/Coils for the following: Model # SSCA075AN Serial # 0277468. but by the coming response i can show only last line in tableview   amp; Coils 3) 2 ea. Unload Normal Solenoid Valves/Coils for the following: Model # SSCA075AN Serial # 0277468

Comment: Running that XML through an XML parser gives you some text where the `&amp;` hasn't been decoded but has had a line break added in the middle of it?! That doesn't sound very likely.

Comment: (Things starting with `&` are character references, not tags. Tags start with `<`)

Answer (score 0):

use below method to remove html tags:

```
- (NSString *)removeHTMLTags:(NSString *)str
{
   NSMutableString *htmlStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];

   NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
   NSString *tempText = nil;

   while (![scanner isAtEnd])
   {
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tempText];

    if (tempText != nil)
        [htmlStr appendString:tempText];

    [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];

    if (![scanner isAtEnd])
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];

    tempText = nil;
  }
  return htmlStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML :(NSString*)targetStr
{
   NSRange r;
   NSString *finalStr = [targetStr copy];
   while ((r = [finalStr rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {
      finalStr = [finalStr stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
   }
   return finalStr;
}
```

reference here m.kocikowski's answer
[Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)