# Parsing Through HTML tags in Objective C ( XCode )

Tags: html, xcode, string, parsing, tags

I'm trying to get string from the following html code

```
<tr class="details">
    <td>
        07/11/2012 09:30
    </td>
    <td>
        something
    </td>
    <td>
        1.0
    </td>
    <td>
        something 2

    </tr></td>
```

I want to get string like "07/11/2012 09:30 something 1.0 something 2". I already have my html code parsed and stored in a NSString called "html". Thinking of getting a string out of this code and then parsing it with NSXMLParser to display it as a single string without this tags in it, but this seems to be a lot of hassle. Should be a easier way to do it. Any way this is the code I am using:

```
NSRange r = [html rangeOfString:@"<tr class="details">"];
    if (r.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange r1 = [html rangeOfString:@"</tr>"];
        if (r1.location != NSNotFound) {
            if (r1.location > r.location) {

                NSString *infoString = [html substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(NSMaxRange(r), r1.location - NSMaxRange(r))];
                NSLog(@"info %@", infoString);
              }
          }
      }
```

I couldn't get away with the semi-colon in the opening tag.

Any ideas how can I implement this task?

Comment: Use a HTML parser of some sort. Is this for iOS or for OS X? [`limbxml2`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) should work on either but might not be the most convenient option available.

Comment: A bit late but this is a good approach it might be useful for someone [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)