# Remove HTML tags from NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

I have a method that i use to remove HTML tags from NSString(i made a category with that):

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    return s;
}
```

The issue is that i want to remove all HTML tags except the `<br>` tags, can i able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak as

First replce `<br/>` with `*br/*` then replace all html tags and then again replace `*br/*` to `<br/>`.

Or, you can use conditional replacing .. if read tag is `br` continue else replace.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:` make sure the tag is not `<br />`.