# How to display string that contain HTML tags in it as plain text

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

I am using google direction api to display map in my mapview and it gives me HTML direction string ,that contain HTML tags.

Now i want to display that string in plain text how can i do that.My strings are here :

```
    Head <b>southwest</b> toward <b>GH Rd</b>
    Exit the roundabout onto <b>GH Rd</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Go through 1 roundabout</div>
    At the roundabout, take the <b>1st</b> exit onto <b>Road Number 2</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Pass by myonlinesearch.blogspot.com (on the left in 600&nbsp;m)</div>
    At the roundabout, take the <b>3rd</b> exit onto <b>CH Rd</b>
    At <b>Indroda Cir</b>, take the <b>2nd</b> exit onto <b>Gandhinagar Ahmedabad Rd/SH 71</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Continue to follow Gandhinagar Ahmedabad Rd</div><div style="font-size:0.9em">Go through 1 roundabout</div>
    At the roundabout, take the <b>1st</b> exit onto <b>Sardar Patel Ring Rd</b>
    At <b>Ranasan Cir</b>, take the <b>3rd</b> exit onto <b>NH 8</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Pass by Galaxy Restaurant (on the left in 4.3&nbsp;km)</div>
    Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Galaxy Rd</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Pass by Shiv Shakti Food Fort (on the left)</div>
    Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>NH 59</b>
    Turn <b>right</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Go through 1 roundabout</div>
    Turn <b>right</b>
   Turn <b>left</b><div style="font-size:0.9em">Destination will be on the right</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RegularExpression/Predicates to remove all characters between < & >.

**But if your text contains some <> it will be removed**

```
  NSRange range;
  NSString *string;
  while ((range = [string rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound){
    string=[string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
  }
  NSLog(@"Un block string : %@",string);
```

Comment: but can this perform action which indicated by that tags
?

Comment: great answer,but still theirs any way to display word bold in <b></b> tags in iphone.

Comment: Use attributed string for that.

Comment: But have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parse the text via a parser it is very easy to parse these text just scan the line and use replace function there.

```
 [yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<b>"withString:""];
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</b>"withString:""];
```

This will  do the trick for you.

Comment: You could go with the above answer if you are getting other tags also

Answer (score 0):

Either you can go with..

```
-(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML 
{
  NSRange r;
  NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return s;
}
```

Or better use NSString category to remove HTML from your string i.e. "GTMNSStringHTMLAdditions".