# TFHpple - getting element HTML without element's tags?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, tfhpple

I'm parsing some HTML and I need to get all the innerHTML of `<body />`. I'm doing it this way:

```
TFHpple *doc = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sectionFilePath]];
TFHppleElement *body = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//body"][0];

NSString *bodyHTML  = body.raw;
```

However this returns:

```
<body>stuff inside body</body>
```

instead of just:

```
stuff inside body
```

> **Question:** Is there any way to get the purely the inner HTML of an element, excluding its own tags?

I came up with this method, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here. This method is also quite slow.

```
TFHppleElement *child;
for(int i = 0; i<body.children.count; i++){
    child = (TFHppleElement*)body.children[i];

    if(child.raw != nil) [bodyHTML appendString:child.raw];
    else if(child.content != nil) [bodyHTML appendString:child.content];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: URL_HERE];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];

NSString *xpathQueryString = @"//body";
NSArray *nodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:xpathQueryString];

for (TFHppleElement *element in nodes) {

    lable.text = [[element firstChild] content];
}
```

Comment: That seems to only give the text of the first element in body, which is not what I am needing...it also seems you copied that from another article?

Comment: add the tags of the other elements like this, @"//body/h1/ul/li" and btw this was from an app I wrote

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem to solve and what i finally did was to get the element.raw with the html format as you get it and just remove the tags with one of the ways that are described here:

[Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

I used stipHtml function.

Comment: Right, my solution was to switch to a different XML Parser, RaptureXML.