# Converting HTML text into plain text using Objective-C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have huge `NSString` with HTML text inside. The length of this string is more then 3.500.000 characters. How can i convert this HTML text to `NSString` with plain text inside.  I was using scanner , but it works too slowly. Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It depends what iOS version you are targeting. Since iOS7 there is a built-in method that will not only strip the HTML tags, but also put the formatting to the string:

**Xcode 9/Swift 4**

```
if let htmlStringData = htmlString.data(using: .utf8), let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlStringData, options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil) {
    print(attributedString)
}
```

You can even create an extension like this:

```
extension String {
    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = self.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Cannot convert html string to attributed string: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this sample code is using UTF8 encoding. You can even create a function instead of computed property and add the encoding as a parameter.

**Swift 3**

```
let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!,
                                              options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                              documentAttributes: nil)
```

**Objective-C**

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

If you just need to remove everything between `<` and `>` (dirty way!!!), which might be problematic if you have these characters in the string, use this:

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML {
   NSRange r;
   NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
   while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
     s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
   return s;
}
```

Comment: I got Out of memory exception on the simulator =(

Comment: How do I replace HTML entities like &amp with their plain text equivalent. i.e. &

Comment: @ThEuSeFuL check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105169/html-character-decoding-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch

Comment: Perfect answer for me. +1 for you.

Comment: Keep in mind, that using NSHTMLTextDocumentType requires to run synchronously on the main thread which is getting locked.

Answer (score 16):

I resolve my question with scanner, but i use it not for all the text. I use it for every 10.000 text part, before i concatenate all parts together. My code below

```
-(NSString *)convertHTML:(NSString *)html {

    NSScanner *myScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    myScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];

    while ([myScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [myScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;

        [myScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;

        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return html;
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
var htmlToString(html:String) -> String {
        var htmlStr =html;
        let scanner:Scanner = Scanner(string: htmlStr);
        var text:NSString? = nil;
        while scanner.isAtEnd == false {
            scanner.scanUpTo("<", into: nil);
            scanner.scanUpTo(">", into: &text);
            htmlStr = htmlStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\(text ?? "")>", with: "");
        }
        htmlStr = htmlStr.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines);
        return htmlStr;
}
```

Comment: add a @autoreleasepool into the while loop for preserving memory

Comment: Note: this will also replace anything between tags, so if you have an email address like "Some Name <his@email.com>" it'll strip out <his@email.com>. That's probably not what you want. It needs to possibly look up against a map of known HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C**

```
+ (NSString*)textToHtml:(NSString*)htmlString
{
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&quot;" withString:@"\""];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&apos;" withString:@"'"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp;" withString:@"&"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
    htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];
    return htmlString;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And why not htmlToText ?

Answer (score 1):

For Swift Language ,

```
NSAttributedString(data:(htmlString as! String).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true
            )!, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSNumber(unsignedLong: NSUTF8StringEncoding)], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString *)inputString
{
    NSMutableString *outString;

    if (inputString)
    {
        outString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:inputString];

        if ([inputString length] > 0)
        {
            NSRange r;

            while ((r = [outString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
            {
                [outString deleteCharactersInRange:r];
            }      
        }
    }

    return outString; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

```
do {
   let cleanString = try NSAttributedString(data: htmlContent.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!,
                                                                      options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                                                                      documentAttributes: nil)
} catch {
    print("Something went wrong")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be more generic by passing encoding type as parameter, but as example as this category:

```
@implementation NSString (CSExtension)

    - (NSString *)htmlToText {
        return [NSAttributedString.alloc
                initWithData:[self dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]
                     options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentOption: NSHTMLTextDocumentType}
          documentAttributes:nil error:nil].string;
    }

@end
```

Comment: in this method where you are passing string may be on self...?

Comment: @Raviteja_DevObal Ah sorry this was category, i could be more clear , will edit ...

Comment: But I don't believe this answer is correct anymore as there ir requirement of large html and this is terribly slow. I ended up using DTCoreText with some additional modifications for showing images correctly my solution is public on github though.

Comment: This method is not converting dynamic HTML text from service.Means i don't know which HTML content is coming from service.But replacing with custom method's

Comment: Sorry that was typo: But I don't believe this answer is NOT correct anymore as there is requirement of large html and this is terribly slow. I ended up using DTCoreText with some additional modifications for showing images correctly my solution is public on github though.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about... If you want to convert any html to text this works, the downside is that it's slow so I don't thing it will work for large html but maybe yes, depends on where you gona use it.