# How to show HTML text from API in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I Am getting a string from API which is "http://www.maximusautogroup.com/\" target=\"_blank\">here". From this string I have to show "here" as an hyperlink of that link. i am not getting how to do that.

Comment: are you using textfield for display this link or label .@Aditya Pandey

Comment: you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/21630187/4970453.  and. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19228078/4970453

Comment: I am using textview .... and the complete string I am getting is "Our official working hours are 9 am to 6 pm ET. We will get back to you on next working day. Please visit <a href=\"http://www.maximusautogroup.com/\" target=\"_blank\">here</a> to know about our claim pr";

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   NSString *FileName = [[Url lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
  NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:FileName];
[attributeString addAttributes:@{NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)
     , NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributeString length])]

        [_buyButton setAttributedTitle:attributeString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```