# How can I get a NSString between two strings in Objective-C on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this NSString:

```
<title>My Friends Website</title>
```

How do I pull out `My Friends Website` into it's own NSString on iOS with Objective-C?

Comment: See the following search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+extract+string+between

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: I'd say this question is a duplicate of what @BlackRider just linked.

Comment: @prototypical The problem with that "duplicate" is it is a more general question about stripping HTML from a string. This question can be solved without the need of regular expressions and all of the other extra overhead. This can be solved with to simple `rangeOfString` calls and a `substringWithRange:` call.

Answer (score 2):

try that:

```
NSString *myString = [[@"<title>My Friends Website</title>" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<title>" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</title>" withString:@""]];
```