# Using NSXMLParser Without Tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I'm parsing an RSS feed with NSXMLParser and it's working fine for the title and other strings but one of the elements is an text thats like

description ![CDATA[ _ p align=right _ 
تنظر محكمة جنايات شمال القاهرة المنعقدة، اليوم الأربعاء، بأكاديمية الشرطة برئاسة المستشار أحمد صبرى يوسف خامس جلسات محاكمة الرئيس السابق محمد مرسى، و14 آخرين من قيادات وأعضاء تنظيم الإخوان الإرهابى، فى قضية اتهامهم بارتكاب أعمال العنف والتحريض على القتل والبلطجة، التى جرت فى محيط قصر الاتحادية الرئاسى فى 5 ديسمبر قبل الماضى. 
وتتضمن قائمة المتهمين ممن أحيلوا لمحكمة الجنايات إلى جانب "مرسى"، القيادى الإخوانى عصام العريان، نائب رئيس حزب الحرية والعدالة، وأسعد الشيخة، نائب رئيس ديوان رئاسة الجمهورية السابق، وأحمد عبد العاطى، مدير مكتب رئيس الجمهورية السابق، وأيمن عبد الرؤوف هدهد، مستشار رئيس الجمهورية السابق، وعلاء حمزة، وعبد الرحمن عز، وأحمد المغير، وجمال صابر، ومحمد البلتاجى، ووجدى غنيم، و4 متهمين آخرين.

]]>

http://www.youm7.com/newhawadesrssnew.asp

every thing going right except that tag - p align=right - appear on the output

what can i  Do To Solve That

xml 
//////////
\

```
<item>
<title><![CDATA[حبس مسن تعدى على طفل جنسيا.. والتحريات تثبت صحة الواقعة]]></title> 
<description><![CDATA[<p align=right>أمر عمرو البنا مدير نيابة الوراق تحت إشراف المستشار ياسر عبد اللطيف رئيس النيابة بحبس مسن أربعة أيام على ذمة التحقيقات التى تجرى معه، لاتهامه بالتعدى على طفل جنسيا، كما أمرت النيابة بعرض الطفل على الطب الشرعى.<br><br>ترجع تفاصيل الواقعة عندما تلقت الأجهزة الأمنية بالجيزة بلاغا من الأهالى يفيد بقيام مسن بهتك عرض طفل، بعد أن تعدى عليه جنسيا داخل كشك ملك للمتهم، حيث يقوم المتهم باستدارج الأطفال بحجة إعطائهم الحلوى ويقوم بالتعدى عليهم.<br><br>وترجع تفاصيل الواقعة عندما قام المتهم ويدعى "إبراهيم.م" 60 سنة صاحب كشك بمنطقة الوراق، بمحاولة استدراج أحد الأطفال ويدعى "م.م" وعندما رفض الطفل قام المتهم بالتعدى عليه رغما عنه، مما أصابه بسحجات وكدمات، فقام بإخبار أسرته، التى تقدمت ببلاغ، وتم ضبط المتهم.<br><br>وأمام النيابة أنكر المتهم ارتكابه الواقعة، ولكن التحريات أثبتت صحتها، أن المتهم اعتاد التعدى جنسيا على الأطفال، وتم عرض الطفل على الطب الشرعى، وحبس المتهم على ذمة التحقيق. </p>]]></description>
<link>http://www.youm7.com//News.asp?NewsID=1490778</link>
<pubDate>Wed, 05 Feb 2014 06:13:57</pubDate>
<guid>http://www.youm7.com//News.asp?NewsID=1490778</guid>
<enclosure url= "http://www.youm7.com//images/newspics/large/S12201313101358.jpg " length="5000" type="image/jpge"/> <!--thumbimage-->
</item>
<item>
<title><![CDATA[حبس صاحب محل بكوم أمبو 4 أيام لحيازته 300 قرص مخدر]]></title> 
<description><![CDATA[<p align=right>أمر محمد الخشن، وكيل النائب العام بأسوان، أمس الثلاثاء، بحبس صاحب محل هواتف محمولة، 4 أيام على ذمة التحقيقات، لضبطه وبحيازته 300 قرص مخدر بمركز كوم أمبو بأسوان.<br><br>كانت مباحث أسوان، برئاسة الرائد رامى نور الدين ومعاونة النقيب أحمد سامى، قد تمكنوا من ضبط "عبد الرحمن.ع.ح" (27 سنة)، صاحب محل إكسسوارات هواتف محمولة، مقيم بعزبة المطحن، دائرة مركز كوم أمبو، وبحيازته 300 قرص مخدر بقصد الاتجار. تحرر عن ذلك المحضر رقم 174 إدارى مركز شرطة كوم أمبو لسنة 2014، وتولت النيابة التحقيق.</p>]]></description>
<link>http://www.youm7.com//News.asp?NewsID=1490762</link>
<pubDate>Wed, 05 Feb 2014 05:24:39</pubDate>
<guid>http://www.youm7.com//News.asp?NewsID=1490762</guid>
<enclosure url= "http://www.youm7.com//images/newspics/large/S1020134171249.jpg " length="5000" type="image/jpge"/> <!--thumbimage-->
</item>
```

and this is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation XMLParser 
@synthesize tweets = _tweets;


NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
NSString *someString;
NSXMLParser     *parser;
Tweet           *currentTweet;
bool            isStatus;

-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _tweets         = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}




- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"pubDate"])
    {
        isStatus = NO;
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if (isStatus) 
    {
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"description"])
        {
            currentTweet.dateCreated = currentNodeContent;
        }
        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"title"])
        {
            currentTweet.content = currentNodeContent;
        }
    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"item"])
    {
        [self.tweets addObject:currentTweet];
        currentTweet = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the raw XML that you are parsing.

Comment: http://www.youm7.com/newhawadesrssnew.asp

Comment: That's doesn't show me the raw XML. Update your question with the actual XML.

Comment: The content in CDATA sections is ignored by the parser. Are you using -parser:foundCDATA: to capture that data?

Answer (score 0):

The CDATA contents for description contain HTML tags. If they appear in your output string it's because you are treating the output as plain/text. Treat it as HTML (or remove the tags if you only want the text).

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATASection {
    // this is HTML text
    NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATASection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: how can i use i my case

Comment: It depends on what you are doing with the result. If what you want is to insert the HTML fragment somewhere else (in a web page) you just get it the way it is.

Comment: If you want to remove the HTML from the result, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: i use it ios app and the result appear like   <<p align=right>> my needed text </p>  i need to remove all the only thing remains is my text

Comment: Then check the first answer to the question I posted in the link above. It shows how you can create a method to strip tags from strings in iOS.

Comment: The first solution is a Category for NSString. If you don't know how to set that up, check the other answers. All of them show ways to remove tags from strings. Basically you apply a regex containing `@"<[^>]*>"` to a string.

Comment: how to get the image from this RSS