# how to remove HTML Tags from NSString in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working Calendar functionality for my app requirement.IF i click today date or tomorrow date or some other date need to display auspicious details in `UITextview`.I have been trying to format a string in my text view but I cant work it out. Im very new to xcode.I want to remove `HTML` Tags in my stringResonse and display in `UITextview`.

I am writing like this in my code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection

{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

if(connection==urlConnection)

{

NSString *strResponse=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"String Response is : %@",strResponse);

NSMutableString *mutString=[NSMutableString string];

NSString *s=nil;

NSString *s1=nil;

//NSArray *arr1=[strResponse componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<br>"]];

NSArray *arr2=[strResponse componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

NSLog(@"array %@",arr2);

for(s in arr2)

{

s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<br>" withString: @"\n"];

s1=[s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<font color>" withString:@" "];

[mutString appendString:@""];

[mutString appendString:s1];

}

text1.text=[text1.text stringByAppendingString:mutString];

}

}

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

strZone=[[NSString alloc]init];

dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];

text1=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 280, 300, 120)];

text1.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

text1.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];

text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

text1.editable=NO;

[self.view addSubview:text1];

}
```

This is my string Response.

```
 S.Panchami 01.38<br>Arudra 02.01<br>V.08.54-10.39<br>D.05.02-06.52<br> <font color=red><u>Festival</u></font><br><font color=blue>Shankara Jayanthi<br></font>
```

But i want to display like this if user clicks date in calendar

S.Panchami 01.38

Arudra 02.01

V.08.54-10.39

D.05.02-06.52

Festival

Shankara Jayanthi

Comment: hi guys this is my string response: S.Panchami 01.38<br>Arudra 02.01<br>V.08.54-10.39<br>D.05.02-06.52<br> <font color=red><u>Festival</u></font><br><font color=blue>Shankara Jayanthi<br></font> ..

Comment: Please add your comment to your question using the edit link and whilst at it please format you question correctly.

Comment: @Popeye i already add my comment in my question.But it is get normal format.so thats why i am add my string response in comment..

Comment: If you want to put it in html format then use the code snippets, like someone has already done for you with the rest of your code

Answer (score 33):

A simple solution with iOS 7:

```
NSString *html = @"S.Panchami 01.38<br>Arudra 02.01<br>V.08.54-10.39<br>D.05.02-06.52<br> <font color=red><u>Festival</u></font><br><font color=blue>Shankara Jayanthi<br></font>";
NSAttributedString *attr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                            options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                      NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                                              error:nil];
NSLog(@"html: %@", html);
NSLog(@"attr: %@", attr);
NSLog(@"string: %@", [attr string]);
NSString *finalString = [attr string];
```

Comment: Of course. I said it was for iOS7. `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` was introduced in iOS7. But since you didn't mention what iOS version you're targetting, and since it could maybe help other users (in the future with only iOS7), I think that it deserve a answer.

Answer (score 8):

If your working with ios 7 then you can apply this code

```
[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

for ios lower than ios 7 use this code,

```
(NSString *) stringByStrippingHTML {
  NSRange r;
  NSString *s = [[self copy] autorelease];
  while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 2):

This should remove all content between `< >`

```
NSString * yourString = @"<br>Arudra 02.01<br>V.08.54-10.39<br>D.05.02-06.52<br> <font color=red><u>Festival</u></font><br><font color=blue>Shankara Jayanthi<br></font>";

NSRange r;
NSMutableString * cleanString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:yourString];
while ((r = [cleanString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
    cleanString = [cleanString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

An option to regular expression is to use `NSScanner`:

```
- (NSString *)removeHTML:(NSString *)str
{
    NSMutableString *pureStr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[str length]];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    scanner.charactersToBeSkipped = NULL;
    NSString *tmp = nil;
    while (![scanner isAtEnd])
    {
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:&tmp];
        if (tmp != nil)
            [html appendString:tmp];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:NULL];
        if (![scanner isAtEnd])
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation] + 1];
        tmp = nil;
    }
    return pureStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a `UIWebView`. If you use a `UITextView`, first you will have to strip the HTML tags from it and then have to insert newline character `\n` for formatting purposes. It would be much easier to wrap your string response with simple HTML format such as `<html><head/><body><your string response><body/></html>` and display it in a `UIWebView`.