# How to parse html text into plain text without attributed string?

Tags: objective-c

How do I parse html text into plain text without attributed string?

This is my code:

```
(NSString *)convertHTML:(NSString *)html {
    NSScanner *myScanner;
    NSString *text = nil;
    myScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:html];
    while ([myScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
        [myScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL];
        [myScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text];
        html = [html stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@""];
    }
    //
    html = [html stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return html;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove HTML Tags from NSString in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to a `UIWEbView` of some kind, you could execute some javascript to retrieve the `.text()` of an element which contains the HTML you want to stringify?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code and get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

```
-(NSString *)stringByStrippingHTML:(NSString*)str
{
    NSRange r;
    while ((r = [str rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location     != NSNotFound)
    {
        str = [str stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    }
    return str;
}

NSString *hstmString = @"This is <font color='red'>simple</font>";

NSString* strWithoutFormatting = [self stringByStrippingHTML:hstmString];

NSLog(@"%@", strWithoutFormatting);
```

It maybe help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If using a library is an option you could try [HTMLKit](https://github.com/iabudiab/HTMLKit).

For example, given the following HTML:

`<p>Some <b>text</b> to <em>extract</em></p>`

one way to parse it to plain text would be:

```
// create a <div> element
HTMLElement *element = [[HTMLElement alloc] initWithTagName:@"div"];
// set its innerHTML
element.innerHTML = @"<p>Some <b>text</b> to <em>extract</em></p>";
// textContext of the element contains all the text
NSLog(@"%@", element.textContent);
// You get: 'Some text to extract'
```

Let me know if you need further help.

> If your HTML is simple and parsing it is not the core functionality of your app/project, then maybe HTMLKit is not for you, since it is a full-fledged HTML parser.

Comment: how align the text which is not properly align . i used attributed string

Comment: @SagarDaundkar what do you mean by "not properly aligned"? Can you please give me an example.