# How to remove HTML tags in iOS?

Tags: html, ios

From my `.plist` I got a string like this:

```
some string + <span class="ppCodeTab">  </span><span class="ppCodeTab"> </span>
```

I use this method:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<span class=``ppCodeTab``>   </span><span class=``ppCodeTab``>   </span>" withString:@""];
```

to replace the span thing but it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `Split` the string.

```
var strings = split(infoString) {$0 == "<span"}
```

The strings[0] will be the "some string"
and you can ignore the rest the rest.