# How to read string between to html node

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsstring

I am getting response from JSON webservice and where I have one node "name".

```
{
    "name": "<style>b\n {\n  font-family:'helvetica';\n  line-height: 200%;\n  text-align: justify;\n } \n </style><b>CORN IDLIS</b><br/>"
}
```

I am trying to get food name between **CORN IDLIS**.

So any one please suggest me how to read or remove all html tag from this node.

Comment: Is your issue about parsing the JSON data or just removing the html code? For the second one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Work properly below code , htmlstring is your html**

```
NSAttributedString *tmp =[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[htmlstring dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUTF8StringEncoding]} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve your string

```
NSString *htmlStr = responseDic[@"name"];
NSArray *tempArray = [htmlStr componentsSeparatedByString:@"<b>"];
NSArray *tempArray1 = [tempArray[1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"</b>"];
NSString *yourString = [tempArray1 firstObject];
```