# Remove html tags and display in UILabel Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am getting *&nbsp /br> p>* like Html tags in my api response. I want to display those contents in `UILabel`

What I did is:

```
NSString *STR_api = [NSString StingWithFormat@:"%@",[API_res valueforkey:@"description"]];
STR_api = [STR_api StringByreplacingaccurancesofString @"&nbsp" with string@""];
```

What I want is, In web portal it is displaying like bold, paragraph is it possible to display in UILabel by formatting the above response

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use `NSAttributedString` to parse the HTML String and display it in a `UILabel`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios)

Comment: Please can you show me your HTML string?

Comment: &nbsp;      Must have Asset Allocation with an experience of less than 3 years with Excellent proficiency    \n\n @user3182143

Comment: Does my answer help you out Sanjay?

Comment: Yeah it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below `UILabel` formatting control which provides Rich text formatting based on HTML-like markups for iOS. 
[RTLabel](https://github.com/honcheng/RTLabel)

Answer (score 5):

I tried from perfect solution from [Larme's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone)

I got the solution.It works fine.

```
NSString *strHTML = @"S.Panchami 01.38<br>Arudra 02.01<br>V.08.54-10.39<br>D.05.02-06.52<br> <font color=red><u>Festival</u></font><br><font color=blue>Shankara Jayanthi<br></font>";
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[strHTML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                            options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                                                      NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute:@(NSUTF8StringEncoding)}
                                                 documentAttributes:nil
                                                              error:nil];
NSLog(@"html: %@",strHTML);
NSLog(@"attr: %@", attrStr);
NSLog(@"string: %@", [attrStr string]);
NSString *finalString = [attrStr string];
NSLog(@"The finalString is - %@",finalString);
```

The printed results are

html

```
html: S.Panchami 01.38<br>Arudra 02.01<br>V.08.54-10.39<br>D.05.02-06.52<br> <font color=red><u>Festival</u></font><br><font color=blue>Shankara Jayanthi<br></font>
```

string

```
string: S.Panchami 01.38
Arudra 02.01
V.08.54-10.39
D.05.02-06.52
Festival
Shankara Jayanthi
```

Final String

```
The finalString is - S.Panchami 01.38
Arudra 02.01
V.08.54-10.39
D.05.02-06.52
Festival
Shankara Jayanthi
```

Now for removing &nbsp from string

**OPTION 1**

```
NSRange range;
while ((range = [finalString rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
finalString = [finalString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

**OPTION 2**

```
finalString = [finalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&nbsp" withString:@""];
```

[Remove HTML Tags from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Comment: but still -  &nbsp; displayed in my label other tags gone .. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
NSString *strDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[API_res valueforkey:@"description"]];

self.lblDescription.attributedText = [self getData:strDescription];
```

Convert HtmlString to string

```
-(NSAttributedString *)getData:(NSString *)str
{
    NSData *stringData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSAttributedString *decodedString;
    decodedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:stringData
                                                     options:options
                                          documentAttributes:NULL
                                                       error:NULL];
    return decodedString;
}
```