# Cant strip out HTML Tags in Swift 3 with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift3, alamofire

Hi I am trying to get rid of html tags within SWIFT 3 and Alamofire, I have the data coming in from web url and a view with a segue going to a second View. In the second table view I am trying to take out html tags, but the code I have got does not do it. Any help?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class nextVC: UIViewController {

    var articleImage = UIImage()
    var articleMainTitle = String()
    var articleContent = String()


    @IBOutlet var mainImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var articleTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var articleContentValue: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        articleTitle.text = articleMainTitle

        mainImageView.image = articleImage

        articleContentValue.text = articleContent

        articleContentValue.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:12)

        _ = articleContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)



    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone/23758318 ?

Comment: nope thats not the answer

Comment: Why are you not doing anything with the string returned after you strip the tags?

Comment: I am fairly new to swift, if you can see a easier way to do it, please elaborate?

Comment: Seems like you should say `articleContentValue.text = articleContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)`

Comment: That worked thanks,  if you want to put it as a answer I can mark it for you..