# NSURLSession: How to return text/plain using Data Task

Tags: objective-c

The following snippet returns text/html data but I want a text/plain string (page content) instead of the html code of the Url.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:1 timeoutInterval:10.0];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

[request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *downloadTask = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            if(error){
                DLog(@"Error: [%@]",error.localizedDescription);
            }
            else{
                NSString* players;
                players = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                DLog(@"DownLoaded Data. Response Data Type[%@] TextEncoding[%@] String[%@]",response.MIMEType,response.textEncodingName,players);
            }
}];
[downloadTask resume];
```

}

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but what's returned is determined by the server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone ? But your question is unclear.

Comment: Does the URL you're requesting support content negotiation?

Comment: [danh] thanks. I forgot the basic rule, the server determines what is returned so I will have to think of another way of accessing the page content or parse the text/html MIME..I should have been clearer ultimately I'm trying to screen scrape the page

Comment: [Julian] thanks for making me aware of content negotiation I will look into it.