# Span Letter Does not separate letters from xml to string in Objective C

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, xml

i am using XML in my project here like this `Span text`

> `span class="qt0">Fitness</span>and<span class="qt3">Exercise</span>`
>   span text can convert to normal string .i tried all code my output will come like this `Fitnessand Exercise` but,i want output like this `Fitness and Exercise` thanks.

Comment: For whom isn't familiar with that XML, why should it be "Fitness and Exercise" and not "FitnessandExercise" (which can be done with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757655/how-to-remove-html-tags-from-nsstring-in-iphone/23758318#23758318) since there is no extra space ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
                    NSRange ran;
                    NSString *san = snippetstr;
                    while ((ran = [san rangeOfString:@"<[^>]+>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound)
                        san = [san stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:ran withString:@""];
                    snippetstr=san;
```