# Remove broken HTML tags from NSString

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

My webservice is returning me HTML content, Sometimes that HTML string might contains incomplete HTML tags

```
e.g: "This is some broken html tag <b"
```

or similler,

Now I am converting it to NSAttributedString during that incomplete tags are causing problems, It would be solved if I could remove these incomplete HTML tags from NSString, Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
- (NSString *)removeIncompleteHTMLTagInString:(NSString *)HTMLString {
    NSArray *subStringByOpenTabs = [HTMLString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<"];
    NSArray *subStringByCloseTabs = [HTMLString componentsSeparatedByString:@">"];
    if (subStringByOpenTabs.count > subStringByCloseTabs.count) {
        return [HTMLString substringToIndex:(HTMLString.length - ((NSString *)[subStringByOpenTabs lastObject]).length) -1];
    }
    else {
        return HTMLString;
    }
}
```

test:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self removeIncompleteHTMLTagInString:@"This is some <xx> broken html tag<b"]);
```

output is: `"This is some <xx> broken html tag"`

Comment: @"This is some <xx> broken html <b tag<b" is not incomplete HTML because it need complete a tag (contain < >)before begin new tag ?

Comment: I want to remove all broken tags

Comment: well HTML format of @"This is some <xx> broken html <b tag<b" is @"This is some <xx> broken html <b tag> <b" or @"This is some <xx> broken html <b ta>g <b" or @"This is some <xx> broken html <b t>ag <b" or @"This is some <xx> broken html <b> tag <b" ?

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**
Save string obtained from web services and update it using:

```
NSString *str=@"This is some broken html tag <b";
[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<b," withString:@""];
```

This will remove all the occurrences of @"

Comment: Its not possible because there might be multiple tags not only <b

Comment: try this question , it works perfectly  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: It removes all html tags, I just want to remove incomplete HTML tags

Comment: you will have to set your own logic for that.You can set a counter or BOOL value when it foinds open TAG , and when it finds corresponding Closed tag , counter o BOOL should reset.Also the number of open tags must be equal to the number of closed tags.if not equal then there willl be some incomplete tag.

Comment: Yes looking for example of the same