# Make href hypertext links in JSON strings work in iOS app

Tags: json, xcode, href, strip

I'm using JSON in my app to call elements from a database.
One of these elements is a text block with href links.

The JSON looks like :

```
"textBlock":"<a href=\"http:\/\/www.website.com\/" target=\"_blank\">Link<\/a>
```

In my app I call label with :

```
self.TextLabel.text = self.item[@"textBlock"];
[selfTextLabel sizeToFit];
```

Result in my app shows :

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

Would it be possible to write / strip this link properly ?

I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone) to strip the html, which works fine, but my links don't work, I would like to know if I can keep my links working.

Comment: Take a look in the regex ?

Comment: Sorry if I don't seem to show any research effort here, but I can't find what I need, that's why I posted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Comment: OK, thanks for the link, I'll check that right away.

Comment: Thanks again, I think I actually allready came across that link, but was a bit affraid of release and dealloc which looked oldschool. I used Leigh McCulloch answer, works nice with some changes, only thing is that links don't work, but I will check a bit further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after some more searching and trying, I finally got what I needed.

I first tried to put my string in UITextView, selectable with links detection. Would have been great if I had written directly my URLs in the text.

But again, the strings I receive from JSON look like :

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

I looked at [Fancy UILabels](http://furbo.org/2008/10/07/fancy-uilabels/) and [NSDataDetector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/), but it seemed like the labels were working but still showing http:// which looked not good for me.

So I figured best way was to put this string in a UIWebView, and call it like (I replaced TextLabel in the question with TextView).

```
[self.TextView loadHTMLString:self.item[@"textBlock"] baseURL:nil];
```

I finally had some last issue, as the links were opening in the UIWebView instead of Safari.

So I added `self.TextView.delegate = self;` in `viewDidLoad`.

And

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)TextView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

.h file must also call `UIWebViewDelegate`.

And if you think UIWebView default font is ugly in this case, like I did, you can do :

```
NSString *nicerTextBlock = self.item[@"textBlock"];
[self.textView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style type='text/css'>body { font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 12 } ></style>%@", nicerTextBlock] baseURL:nil];
```

Hope this can spare some time for other people.