# How to get the string size of string with html content

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can get the string size using This method

```
[myString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName :myFont}
```

but, my string has HTML content , I tried to do it like this

```
[myString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,NSFontAttributeName :myFont}
```

but,I got a wrong value ?
also I tried to use `NSAttributedString` like this

```
NSAttributedString * tabText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,myFont: NSFontAttributeName} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
CGSize mySize=[tabText size];
```

And also I got  a wrong value .

**my string is very basic HTML content like "`test &amp; test`" it returns**
 **the width of 15 chars not 11**

Comment: Wrong how? What HTML?

Comment: very basic HTML content like "test &amp; test" it returns the width of 15 chars not 11

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the html tags first, use this as reference - [Remove HTML Tags from an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Then get the string size, try this:

```
CGSize stringSize = [YOUR_STRING sizeWithAttributes: @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];

// ceilf - is used to get equivalent values
CGSize currentSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(stringSize.width), ceilf(stringSize.height));
```

Comment: what if my string like this  "test &amp; test" ?