# How to remove HTML tags from string - Objective C

Tags: html, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

How to remove `HTML` tags from string, So string is as follows:

```
myString = @"<a href=\"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/sports/off-the-field/hamiltons-social-silence-has-the-f1-fans-talking/articleshow/62462341.cms\"><img border=\"0\" hspace=\"10\" align=\"left\" style=\"margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;\" src=\"https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/62462341.cms\" /></a>Lewis Hamilton's social media posts have long been a talking point in Formula One but the absence of any from the four times world champion so far this year is also attracting attention.";
```

After modification my string should be as follows:

```
newString = @"Lewis Hamilton's social media posts have long been a talking point in Formula One but the absence of any from the four times world champion so far this year is also attracting attention.";
```

What should I use to get above newString from myString?

Comment: see this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277055/remove-html-tags-from-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: @Nirav Kotecha Thank you